# Slide Toggle & toggle Class

Tags: jquery, toggle, show, show-hide, slidetoggle

I'm creating a header for a mobile site that has 2 icons - one for basket and one for help section and when each is clicked a dropdown appears with further information.

I need to get it to work so only one dropdown appears at any one time and that the inactive icons inner span class should return to class 'fa-chevron-down'.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2srx4sv2/

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="format-detection=no,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0,width=device-width" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/test_new/css/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/test_new/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/test_new/js/mobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <ul class="hdr_link_icons">
        <li class="icon_basket"><img src="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/test_new/images/header/icon_basket.jpg" alt="My basket" /><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></li>
        <li class="icon_help"><img src="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/test_new/images/header/icon_help.jpg" alt="Help Section" /><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></li>
    </ul>    
    <ul class="hdr_dropdown_area" id="help_dropdown">
        <li><a href="">Your Account <span class="hdr_link_arrow">&#187;</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">Corporate Sales <span class="hdr_link_arrow">&#187;</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">Got a voucher? <span class="hdr_link_arrow">&#187;</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="dvBasket" class="basketoverview hdr_dropdown_area">
        <div class="heading">Total items: 1</div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="details">
                <a href="#">
                    Product 1
                </a> 
                <br />
                <span class="price">£39.00</span>
            </div>        
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="details">
                <a href="#">
                    Product 2
                </a> 
                <br />
                <span class="price">£39.00</span>
            </div>        
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">        
            <a title="Your basket" href="#">View Basket</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('.icon_help').click(function () {
        $("#help_dropdown").slideToggle('slow');
        $(".icon_help .fa-chevron-down, .icon_help .fa-chevron-up").toggleClass( 'fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');      
        $(".basketoverview").slideUp('slow');  
    });
    $('.icon_basket').click(function () {
        $(".basketoverview").slideToggle('slow');
        $(".icon_basket .fa-chevron-down, .icon_basket .fa-chevron-up").toggleClass( 'fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');  
        $("#help_dropdown").slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2srx4sv2/1/ something like this?

Comment: Hi nevermind, thanks for this - the toggle works perfectly but the class on on the span for the inactive icon doesn't change back to '.fa-chevron-down' - any ideas?

Comment: Hm... as i can see class is changed in HTML, on click (checked in console) - so, i guess that just right css should be added?

Comment: If I click the help icon and then I click the basket icon, the help dropdown slides up and the basket dropdown slides down but this line of code: <li class="icon_help"><img alt="Help Section" src="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/test_new/images/header/icon_help.jpg"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></li> should look like: <li class="icon_help"><img alt="Help Section" src="http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/test_new/images/header/icon_help.jpg"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></li>